# Elasticsearch: How do I reference a nested field name using Painless script in a curl command

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-painless

I have a painless script that works in the console but fails in curl.  The script references a nested field (event.orinal).

In the Kibana console, this statement works fine:
`ctx._source.event.remove('original')`

In a curl statement, I get this result:

```
...
"ctx._source.event.remove(original)",
"                         ^---- HERE"
]
...
"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"cannot resolve symbol [original]"}},"status":400}
```

We have an elastic subscription, but support has repeatedly stated that help with this is 'out of scope' because curl is not an elastic product.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full cURL request and response:

```
curl -XPOST "https://<server>:9200/<index>/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed" -u <creds> --cacert <certpath> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.event.remove(original)",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "event.original" }
    }
}'

{
  "error":
    {
      "root_cause":[
        {
          "type":"script_exception",
          "reason":"compile error",
          "script_stack":
            [
              "ctx._source.event.remove(original)",
              "                         ^---- HERE"
            ],
          "script":"ctx._source.event.remove(original)",
          "lang":"painless",
          "position":
              {
                "offset":25,
                "start":0,
                "end":34
              }
        }
      ],
      "type":"script_exception",
      "reason":"compile error",
      "script_stack":
        [
          "ctx._source.event.remove(original)",
          "                         ^---- HERE"
        ],
      "script":"ctx._source.event.remove(original)",
      "lang":"painless",
      "position":
        {
          "offset":25,
          "start":0,
          "end":34
        },
      "caused_by":
        {
          "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason":"cannot resolve symbol [original]"
        }
    },
  "status":400
}
```

Comment: **The following statement is not working just running.** Because there is no hit for the following filter `    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "event.original" }
    }`. The reason for "0" hits is the `event.original field` is nested and you need to add `nested.path: event` inside of the exist filter. If you add that you will see the error.

Comment: There was not a problem with `"query" : { "exists": { "field": "event.original" } }`.  After the escaped double quotes on `"ctx._source.event.remove(\"original\")"` it worked fine,.

Comment: Again... It's not working it's running. the `query exist filter` is broken. I edited my answer below check that.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT : Your query is running NOT working.

You will always get the following result.

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 0,     <---- "0" results.
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 0,
  "version_conflicts": 0,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": []
}
```

Try with [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html).
Here is the documentation for [foreach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/foreach-processor.html) processor of ingest pipeline.

```
PUT test_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "event": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST test_nested/_doc/1
{
  "event": [
    {
      "original": "nested_value_1",
      "other_field": "first_value"
    },
    {
      "original": "nested_value_2",
      "other_field": "second_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/remove_nested_field
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "event",
        "processor": {
          "remove": {
            "field": "_ingest._value.original"
          }
        },
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
POST test_nested/_update_by_query?pipeline=remove_nested_field
```

---

```
GET test_nested/_search
```

Reference: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ingest-processor-failure-when-accessing-nested-field/144194/2

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the proposal @Musab-Dogan.  It would have worked without the special circumstances that required me to use a painless script with curl.  The posted question was the ability to access a nested field name with painless script using curl.  I did eventually figure it out through trial and error, and I posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

an ingest pipeline might have worked.  I originally tried an ingest pipeline, but it failed due to the record size.  Long story on how this happened, but it was not possible.

I did figure out how to access a nested field in painless using curl, however.  it requires escaped double quotes (\") around the nested field name.

```
curl -XPOST "https://<server>:9200/<index>/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed" -u <creds> --cacert <certpath> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.event.remove(\"original\")",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "event.original" }
    }
}'
```